# PHP parsing technique

Tags: php, state-machine

Can any one give me some idea about how does a php file get parsed? I'm actually looking for the finite state machine structure for the parser. If anyone has any idea please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses bison/yacc to generate a parser. Have a look at the grammar here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_parser.y?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

You better use an existing one:

[Any decent PHP parser written in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586358/any-decent-php-parser-written-in-php)