# Regular Expression to get anything between two strings '$' and ';' and not preceded by '//'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds

I got the following code

```
$original_file=str_replace('<?php','',file_get_contents('file.txt'));

//regular expression to get anything that starts with '$' and end with ';'
preg_match_all("/\\$(.*?);/",$original_file,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

I have succeeded in the getting the variables or anything starting with the '$', But now I am trying to modify that regular expression to lookbehind the $ and check if it is preceded by the \ comments keywords. if it is then don't get it.Does someone have a good suggestion? I am using PHP preg_match_all as you can see above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: \\ isn't a PHP comment, it's //

Comment: If you are trying to parse PHP in PHP, you may have a look into [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586358/any-decent-php-parser-written-in-php). Or even [token_get_all()](http://php.net/token_get_all) function.

Comment: Guillaume Poussel, no I am not, but the information is very interesting I may use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
preg_match_all("~(?<!//)\$([^;]*);~", $original_file, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: anubhava, my mistake the preceding string was '//' not '\\', should it not be something like preg_match_all("/(?<!\\//)\$([^;]*);/", $original_file, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);? I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: is this fine with you? preg_match_all("/(?<!\\/)\\$(.*?);/",$original_file,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); I modified your suggestion to this and it did work!

Comment: Yes that also appears fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @anubhava but using `s` option for  traversing over all the `$str` lines,

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\\\)\$([^;]+);/s', $str, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

To avoid generic match, use the variable syntax (supposing alphanumeric variables like PHP variables),

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<!\\\)\$([a-z0-9_]+);/si', 
    $str, 
    $m, 
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
);
```

without this little enhance, your parser will catch wrong syntax, in the case of

```
$str = "\nTEST\n\n \$x;\$y;\ny\$y_ \$_X;";
```

For a complete "template parsing" see the [Smallest Tempalte System](https://code.google.com/p/smallest-template-system/) concepts and discussions.

Comment: Hello @user1518071, it is not only "for precision", check by your self the test (I edited now illustrating with a `$str` value) showing an error case of the "generic match".