# Regular Expressions for string in php to find the word in commas

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a Regexp for php to scan true files, the keyword is `require` and the string I want is in brackets `"my string"` (require would be reserved) example

**File1.txt**

```
require "testing/this/out.js"
require "de/test/as.pen"
require "my_love.test"

.....

print "I require coffee in the morning" //problem
```

- The requires will be at the top of the page.
- Follow the standard `require "_String_"` format

---

**File2.txt**

```
Class Ben extends Name

....

print "My good boss always extends my deadline" //problem
```

- Extends would only be follow by class name
- Is only one word and only one result

---

```
// looping true and determining if class or if reg file by folder structure
$subject = "Code above";
$pattern = '/^require+""/i'; // Not sure of the correct pattern
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I just want `testing this out` and `de/test/as.pen` to return in an array for the first example.

Is this possible? will there be a lot of problems with this?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to be sure that `require` is not inside a string?

Comment: Are you trying to build a map of the dependencies between your files by collecting the `require`, and classes extending other classes and so on ? I really don't understand what you're trying to do from the description of your problem, so I'm guessing...

Comment: @Martin Yes im trying to build a dependency system. the regex is what I dont understand. Its the best way i think that will work.

Comment: I would definitely use a parser and inspect the outputted AST for that. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586358/any-decent-php-parser-written-in-php (Here's the parser he wrote : https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). If you don't know what an AST is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
$pattern = '/^ *require +"([^"]+)"/i';
```

Comment: Should this be a case sensitive regex?

Comment: Probably not, I just copied that part from question

Answer (score 1):

```
^require (['"])([.\w /]+)\1
```

match the result:

```
preg_match('#^require (['"])([.\w /]+)\1#', $code, $match);
```

***Explanation***:

```
^               #  Start of string
require         #  reserved word with an space after
(['"])          #  Quotations
(               #  Capturing group
    [.\w /]+    #   Any possible characters
)               #  End of capturing group
\1              #  Same quotation
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jV1bG6)

Comment: Your question is very correct but its not working correctly. Check out this js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/zcFEm/4/ Its almost works but the require is included. `/gm` are just two global/mutlyline flags.

Comment: @CezarisLT You should refer to 2nd captured group. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/fcCP4/

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to skip content inside quotes:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(["']) (?> [^"'\\]++ | \\{2} | \\. | (?!\1)["'] )* \1 # content inside quotes
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # forces this possibility to fail
|
(?>^|\s)
require \s+ " ([^"]++) "
~xs
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```