# Use php to scan a .php file for all of its methods and classes

Tags: php, file-io

I would like to **create a script** that would **open a php file** and tell me it's content, but i want to know if there is a class in there and if so, what methods are there, what parameters are they waiting for, and so on and so forth.

So basically it would work a little bit like phpDocumentor, at least that is how i imagine it.

Could you please point me in to the right direction, i all ready googled it and of course i tried **file_get_contents()** but that didn't gave me the class.

Comment: So basically implement a PHP parser...

Comment: @MarcB well yes Marc, you could say that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8374698/1563558 this might help

Comment: just a sec i'll give it a try @DannyHearnah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php may help you within php.

---

Not the same thing but;

also see http://xdebug.org/

and maybe http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof

They might help you too.

Edit: By the way, phpDoc also shows the code.

Comment: I really like the show_source function but how would i proceed to see analyze a class?

Comment: I think that Hilmi means to look at the source code of `show_source()` and `xdebug`, not to actually use that function or tool.

Comment: Ohh, ok, sorry my bad. Well thanks, i really think that these links are a good start.