# Eclipse JUNO PHP Formatter

Tags: php, code-formatting, eclipse-juno

I've downloaded the Eclipse PDT package as well as however, I can't find any options for formatting my PHP such as specifying line breaks, etc.

In this answer to another question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517764, there is a screenshot of what I understand is what I should be seeing. However, all I see is an extremely basic setting panel where I can set whether or not I want spaces or tabs to be used and how many to be used.

Any help on getting a good formatter would be great.
Ideally, it'd be a formatter for within Eclipse as opposed to another tool.

I'm currently using Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

From what I see, PDT 3.1.x branch doesn't have a fully customizable code formatting rules. If you go and install/update to PDT 3.2 branch you'll get java-like code formatting options.

In Eclipse Juno go to:

```
Help > Install New Software
```

- Click the "Add" button that appears near the top right
- For Name you can put "PDT 3.2 Release" (or whatever you want really)
- For Location you HAVE to put http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.2/release

Once you update/install PDT and restart eclipse if you go to

```
Window > Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Formatter
```

You'll see a highly customizable formatter to use.

Note, I got the link for the 3.2 release from: http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt